# The Maximum Distance in an Oval Shape

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was trying to answer the following question from *Calculus, a Complete Course* by Adams. To me it seemed simple but I encountered some problems.

> An oval table has its outer edge in the shape of the curve $x^2+y^4=1/8$, where $x$ and $y$ are measured in meters. What is the width of the narrowest wall in which the table can be turned horizontally through $180^{\circ}$?

This is a question in the chapter on the applications of differentiation. However, I think this can be solved easily by taking a geometrical approach. This is the shape drawn in Desmos [image]

The answer is clearly twice the distance between the origin and the point $(0,0.595)$:
$$2D=2\sqrt[4]{\frac{1}{8}}\approx 1.1892 m$$

But when I find the critical point of the function of the distance between the origin and the curve, I get $y=1/\sqrt2$ which doesn't make sense, since it does not lie on the curve. Here is my calculation: $$x^2+y^4=1/8$$
$$x^2=1/8-y^4$$
The distance function $D$ (the distance between the origin and point $(x,y)$ on the curve) is:

$$D(x,y)=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)=\sqrt(1/8-y^4+y^2)$$
$$\frac{dD}{dy}=\frac{-4y^3+2y}{2\sqrt(1/8-y^4+y^2)}$$

The critical points $y=0$ and $y=\pm1/\sqrt2$. But this point does not lie on the curve. And by using the critical point I get the answer to be $1.225 m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For what range of $y$ is $x=\sqrt{1/8-y^4}$ a valid solution to $x^2+y^4=1/8$, and does that include $y=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: So dumb of me to miss that. Thank you. So the answer is 1.189 m

Comment: @KavehRad yes, gotta watch out for domain sneakiness. Another minor refinement is that  $x^2+y^2$ is easier to differentiate and has the same maximum as its square-root. (This is the same logic in statistics for minimizing the mean squared error vs the mean absolute error.)